# Проверка значения Excel на соответствие шаблону

Tags: c#

```
string line6 = excelSheet.Cells[j, 6].Value.ToString();
int length6 = line6.Length;
if (length6 == 11)
{                      
   if (line6[0] == '8' || line6[0] == '7' && line6.Where((x, y) => y !=0).All(char.IsDigit))
   {
     excelSheet.Rows[j].Delete();
     j--;
   }
}
```

Проверяю ячейку со значением 890515-4330. Почему то не находит "-" и пропускает ошибку. "-"явно не число.Помогите выявить причину.

Answer (score 0):

Ваше условие можно переписать в виде

```
if (line6[0] == '8' || (line6[0] == '7' && line6.Where((x, y) => y !=0).All(char.IsDigit)))
```

поэтому по первому условию `line6[0] == '8'` ваше значение проходит (если я правильно понял, что ошибка заключается в том, что выполняется тело цикла). так как используется `||` проверка того, что все символы цифры не выполняется

могу предположить, что имелось в виду

```
if ((line6[0] == '8' || line6[0] == '7') && line6.Where((x, y) => y !=0).All(char.IsDigit))
```